# What do do when the number of choices depends on your previous choice? (Discrete mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, recursion

Say I have three objects: Object A, B, and C.
I may not choose object B two times in a row.
How many choices would there be for n = 2? n=3?

My goal is to find a recurrence relation for this, but I am struggling to understand how this would even work mathematically.

Answer (score 2):

Call a string *good* if it does not contain the substring $BB$, and let $g_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$. How many good strings of length $n+1$ can be made from a good string of length $n$? As you’ve realized, it depends on whether the string of length $n$ ends in $B$, so let’s keep track of those separately: let $b_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ that end in $B$, and let $a_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ that do not end in $B$. Clearly $a_n+b_n=g_n$.

Suppose that $s$ is a good string of length $n$. No matter what letter is at the end of $s$, we can add an $A$ or a $C$ to get a good string of length $n+1$, and if $s$ does not end in $B$, we can also add a $B$. Thus, we get $2g_n$ good strings of length $n+1$ that end in $A$ or $C$, and $a_n$ good strings of length $n+1$ that end in $B$, so $a_{n+1}=2g_n$, $b_{n+1}=a_n$, and $g_{n+1}=2g_n+a_n$.

We’re getting there, but we still have to figure out how to get rid of that $a_n$ term. In this case that turns out to be pretty easy: we discovered that $a_{n+1}=2g_n$, which immediately tells us that $a_n=2g_{n-1}$ and hence that $g_{n+1}=2g_n+2g_{n-1}$ or, if you prefer, that $g_{n+1}=2(g_n+g_{n-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $w_n$ denote the number of ways of choosing the objects $n$ times, so that the last chosen object (object chosen the $n^{th}$ time) is not $B$.
Then we cab derive the following recurrence relation for $w_n$:

$$w_n=2(w_{n-1}+w_{n-2})$$
This is because in the $n^{th}$ round either $A$ or $C$ has to be chosen, according to our defintion of $w_n$ and there are two options upto the $(n-1)^{th}$ round:

1. Either, $B$ is not chosen in the $(n-1)^{th}$ round which can be done in $w_{n-1}$ ways
2. Or, $B$ was chosen in the $(n-1)^{th}$ round, then it was not chosen in the $(n-2)^{th}$ round, which can be done in $w_{n-2}$ ways.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can easily calculate by hand that $w_0=1$, $w_1=3$, $w_2=8$, and $w_3=22$, data that are not consistent with your recurrence.

Comment: How would you do such calulation though? Im guessing you are saying that first time its 3, which makes sense, but could you explain how you got 8 and 22?

Comment: I was wrong in the factor $3$, which I have edited. But $w_2=6$ and $w_3=18$

Comment: @Gleb: The only bad string of length $2$ is $BB$, and there are $3^2=9$ possible strings of length $2$, so $8$ of them must be good. (You can easily list them: $AA,AB,AC$, $BA,BC$, $CA,CB,CC$.) There are $3^3=27$ strings of length $3$, and $5$ are bad — $ABB,CBB,BBA,BBC$, and $BBB$ — so $22$ are good.

Comment: @QED: Your figures for $w_2$ and $w_3$ are incorrect. You seem to be calculating the wrong thing: you say that $w_n$ is the number that don’t end in $B$, but that’s not what’s wanted.

Comment: Yeah I know, but calculating $w_n$ is the crux of the problem. Once you obtain $w_n$, the total number of ways can be obtained by $w_{n}+w_{n-1}$.